# Hide Url extensions using React-Router-Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `react-router-dom` to create client-side pages within a React site.  This extension is working fine but I'm wondering if there is a way I can hide the URL extensions from appearing within the browser navigation bar.

Here is my code:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/airports">Airports</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/cities">Cities</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/courses">Courses</Link></li>
        </ul>

        <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
        {/* You don't always have to render a whole component */}
        <Route path="/airports" render={() => (<div> This is the airport route </div>)}/>
        <Route path="/cities" component={City}/>
        <Route path="/courses" component={Courses}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So clicking on **Airports** will show `www.myurl.com/airports`, clicking on **Cities** shows `www.myurl.com/cities`.  Since these pages are created client-side and not server-side, I'd really like to hide these extensions so that whenever I click on these links, it will just show the host name of `www.myurl.com`.

Hopefully there is an easy way of accomplishing this.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you know the websites that use such technique?

Comment: @KamranPoladov I do not, sorry.

Comment: Even though the question is pretty compelling, I don't see any reasons to hide the extensions. How are users gonna navigate to particular page of your website then? Can you offer any alternatives?

Comment: @KamranPoladov So users would navigate through links within the site itself.  This problem arose when I deployed my React app and realized that the links from these sections (e.g. Airports, Cities) are client-side links and will ultimately produce 404 errors if you try typing them in the browser address bar.  So I don't want users to see these urls and think they are "Live" pages when they really aren't.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Pretty useful

Comment: @KamranPoladov No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: [This is a sort of hack that works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57216739/6331353)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. **Using [Memory History](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md)**

From the docs:

> Memory history doesn't manipulate or read from the address bar. This
>   is how we implement server rendering. It's also useful for testing and
>   other rendering environments (like React Native).

Use one like so:

```
const history = createMemoryHistory(location)
render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path='about' component={About} />
      <Route path='features' component={Features} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

2. **Using [MemoryRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/4abe54152400fb987e31d063ad85293551db0032/packages/react-router/docs/api/MemoryRouter.md)**

From the docs:

> A Router that keeps the history of your "URL" in memory (does not
>   read or write to the address bar). Useful in tests and non-browser
>   environments like React Native.

```
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router'

<MemoryRouter>
  <App/>
</MemoryRouter>
```

Comment: I tried using both methods but only the `MemoryRouter` method worked for me.  This is perfect and was exactly what I needed, thank you @Paras.

Comment: @JeffP. You should really need to switch the component instead of using router.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I definitely look into using the switch component.