# Is it possible to hide secret URL paths when using React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to React, and have a n00b question and Googling hasn't turned up any good answers, maybe someone here knows:

With React Router or any kind of declarative routing, how do you "hide" private URLs that you don't want every user to know about?  Or, if you just want to prevent someone from being able to easily enumerate all valid URLs?

Code splitting doesn't solve this (really) because the user is told what to request to get the rest of the information: I suppose you could put that URL behind authentication or some kind of restriction to prevent public access to it, but won't that cause the JS fetching the code-split import to receive an error, causing that error to bubble up and cause unintended failure behavior?

Edited to add:

The crux of my issue is wanting to essentially do `<Route path="/:path">` where `:path` matches the entire URL path (e.g., could be `foo/bar/baz`) instead of just the first "part" (e.g., `foo`) for a URL like `https://example.com/foo/bar/baz` for example.

I could use `<Route path="*">` and do my own URL parsing, but what if I don't want that route to actually handle the request? How do I signal "nope, I don't want this request, fall-through to the next matching Route"?

Comment: Did that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52681342/hide-url-extensions-using-react-router-dom can help you ?

Comment: @mehdim2 Unfortunately, no.  I want to hide the entire route, basically link to pages whose contents will be fetched from the server but not provide a list of all the possible URLs at build time in the router.  I thought about using a route like `/:path` but that won't work if the URL is `/foo/bar` right?  `:path` will stop at the first `/` won't it?

Comment: You can't without server-side rendering. React runs on the client side usually, which means the user can see everything you render in it if they want to. The best way to "hide" things like this wouldn't be at the application level but within a forward proxy with networking rules or similar, or simply return 403 if the user isn't authorized.

Comment: @Dan My understanding is that SSR can limit the content behind the routes from being loaded by the user, but I'm looking to eliminate the disclosure of the existence of the routes to the user at all.

Comment: You can handle a particular route that you want to make private inside the component. In that way, it will not be exposed to all routers and putting a condition on the private route (possibly any appropriate `if` statement). That way you will have control to whom to show that private route.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user is authorized to see these routes and then show or hide them.

```
<Route path="/cities" component={City} />
<Route path="/courses" component={Courses} />
{user.hasPermission && (
  <Route path="/secret" component={VerySecretPage} />
)}
```

If you want to go further, you can create a [custom guarded route](https://blog.netcetera.com/how-to-create-guarded-routes-for-your-react-app-d2fe7c7b6122) as described in this blog post.

Comment: My question isn't about guarding routes, but how do I not disclose the existence of those routes at ALL in the React app?  Guarded routes prevent the user from accessing the route "in the browser" but all the code behind it is still being sent down to the user, unless you use code splitting, but even just disclosing the existence of the route can be undesirable - how do we avoid that?

Comment: React is a client side framework, for this to happen you'd need to work with a framework such as NextJS, that allows the server to only disclose such information if a user is authenticated.